# Cannot understand error message -- Haskell

Tags: haskell

when I tried to use cabal run to test my code there is an error message

"  no location info : error:
Failing due to -Werror."

Can anyone explain to me what this mean and what may cause this error?

Comment: Well there are some warnings printed in the console, and `-Werror` says that if there are warnings, then this should be considered a (fatal) error by the compiler. So you need to solve the warnings above.

Comment: Except for [haskell], the tags you had added were not relevant to the question. Please read the tag descriptions before adding them.

Comment: When I google *"ghc werror"*, the very first result tells me exactly the answer you need. I strongly recommend doing at least minimal research before asking a question here.

Comment: To get a good answer, provide more context. For example: what source code is in what files?

Answer (score 2):

If you compile with the [**`-Werror`** flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#ghc-flag--Werror) then this means that warnings are treated like (fatal) errors, as specified in the documentation:

> make warnings fatal

So from the moment the compiler emits a warning (you can look for warnings in the output by the compiler), then the compilation is considered non-successful.

Usually warnings by the compiler denote something that does not look right, but is not fatal in the sense that the compiler *can* produce a binary. For example if you define a function like:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = 0
```

then Haskell can - if the `-Wunused-matches` is enabled - produce a warning saying that the `x` in the head of the function is not used in the body. This is odd, perhaps you forgot to use `x`. We can however use a wildcard pattern in case we do not need this:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f _ = 0  -- no warning
```

Some projects thus use this to "prevent" letting pass such warnings unnoticed.